# What does the Dark Mark on Harry Potter's hand mean?

Tags: harry-potter

What does the Dark Mark on Harry's arm mean, and why does he have it if it was only meant for Voldemort's inner circle?

> **DUMBLEDORE :** *Barty Crouch Junior.*
>
> **BARTY JR :** *I'll show you mine if you show me yours.*
>
> Barty Jr rolls up his sleeve to reveal a skull and snake marking.
>
> **DUMBLEDORE :** *Your arm Harry.*
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - Film</sup></sub>

[image: A close up of Harry's arm showing the mark/wound]

Comment: i dont think harry got a dark mark on his arm.

Comment: Do you maybe mean the scar that was left after Wormtail took Harrys blood in Goblet of Fire?

Comment: yeah, that one.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be more, "What is the mark on Harry's hand from, and what does it mean." Then provide reference to the scene with Barty Crouch Junior in the details of the question. As it stands, "Harry doesn't have a Dark Mark." is the only correct answer.

Comment: Besides the scar where Wormtail took his blood, there's also the scar Umbridge's quill has left.  Harry shows this latter to Rufus Scrimgeour in *Hallows*.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - I've edited the question to show what he meant, a bit more clearly.

Comment: it's not a dark mark, it's the wound from Wormtail. Crouch's words in the film are just a joke on the old schoolyard "you show me yours" thing

Answer (score 28):

Harry doesn't have a Dark Mark.

The mark you are referring to is the knife wound that Harry suffered when Wormtail took Harry's blood for Voldemort's new body.

Comment: But in Goblet of Fire, Barty Crouch Junior saw Harry's dark mark.

Comment: @chinmayee No he didn't. You're either misremembering or misinterpreting a section of the book. Can you provide an actual quote?

Comment: In Goblet of Fire movie, Barty Crouch Junior says, 'I'll show you mine, if you show me your' and then Dumbledore shows Harry's hand and he had something on his hand.

Comment: @chinmayee Not a "dark mark", but the spot where Harry's blood had been forcibly taken to bring back Voldemort. Debateable, but I believe that quote was Crouch looking for proof that Voldemort was really back.

Comment: Why would Barty want to see his arm, how did he know that harry's arm would be cut if Voldy was back? Seems like a stretch.

Comment: @Stephan, Crouch Jr was heavily involved in the entire plan, was present when it was conceived: he knew what Voldemort was gonna do as well as where it would take place.

Answer (score 0):

In the film, I think it's for dramatic effect. The dark Mark, the sign of evil and, for many, cowardice, against Harry's bravery. In this scene, blood doesn't carry negative connotations as it often does but rather reinforces the fact that Harry still has blood in his veins and has once again survived. The juxtaposition of the two "marks" is a powerful image. It is also, perhaps, a hint at the link between Harry and Voldemort's respecive survivals- a hint at what is to be revealed in later instalments. However, as the comparison doesn't happen in the books I don't think it's significant in terms of plot or explanation.

Comment: If the filmmakers mentioned this anywhere, that would help your answer.

Comment: This is confusing